# Can anyone use tikz to draw a three-dimensional schematic diagram of the mesh surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

Can anyone use tikz to draw a three-dimensional schematic diagram of the mesh surface[image]

Comment: Just need to draw a rough 3D schematic diagram

Comment: It’s almost the same as the in the diagram

Comment: Also there is a diagonal line in each rectangle.